# What's the best way to read a matrix of unknown columns from standard input?

Tags: c++, c

I know only the number of rows `r` in a matrix.

How do I read it into a multi-dimensional array `arr[MAX][MAX]`?

I thought of reading all the elements into a single array, count the no. of elements and then adding them to arr in groups of `count/r`. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Is there a newline character at the end of each row?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that everything may as well go into contiguous memory so just keep pushing it at the end of `std::vector<double>`.  At the end you know its length, and given that you know `r`, you now also know the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have nothing but the number of rows and a list of data values, just read the whole thing into a vector, and then divide the size of the vector by the number of rows to get the number of columns. You should, however, also know whether the data is stored row-wise or column-wise. On this depends how to index the vector (I would keep the data in the vector and access it through index calculation, most probably encapsulated in a nice little class).